# Python - Is there any swagger for Spyne RPC toolkit?

Tags: spyne

I have been provided with a project where the API is written with [spyne](http://spyne.io/#inprot=HttpRpc&outprot=JsonDocument&s=rpc&tpt=WsgiApplication&validator=true). Now I have to implement a swagger UI (if there is any) for this project. I have done my research but couldn't find any. Is it actually possible to integrate a swagger?

Comment: It's of course possible. I'd be happy to review and merge a patch that implements swagger as another interface document.